# Issue while saving checked Rows using Ultragrid in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics

I am newbie to Infragistics Controls.
Currently I am working with UltraGrid in C#.net and facing an issue while saving the selected rows by using the checkbox style property.

I am displaying only selected rows in the UltraGrid, and at the time of loading the rows into the grid, the checked values and unchecked values are displaying properly. However, when saving, only the recently checked rows are considered, and the rows which are checked by default are not - it throws null at the time of saving. Only the recently selected rows are getting saved.

Please help me here to get rid of this issue.

Comment: I am not sure what is being asked here.  Do you have code that shows what you are doing?  What is null?  If an exception is being thrown, do you have a call stack?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where the last checkbox checked was not up to date when attempting to save values in only the checked rows - a call to `yourUltraGrid.UpdateData()` worked for me.

If that doesn't help, what code are you using to set the 'default rows'? That might help shed some further light on your issue.

Best of luck!